# Can $a^n+F_n$ be prime for every integer $a>1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

I have the following conjecture :

> Let $a>1$ be an integer. Then, there is a positive integer $n$ such that $a^n+F_n$ is prime , where $F_n$ denotes the $n$-th fibonacci number.

For $a\le 10^4$ , there is a positive integer $n\le 594$ , that $a^n+F_n$ is not divisible by one of the first $30\ 000$ primes, so it seems that we cannot show for some $a$ (for example by a cover) that $a^n+F_n$ is composite for every positive integer $n$.

On the other hand , there are tough cases (no prime upto $n=5\ 000$) , the first few are $a=13,19,43,48,51,57$. For the case $a=13$ , no $n\le 35\ 000$ gives a prime.

Considering the growth rate, I think the conjecture should be true. Any ideas how to prove or disprove it ?

Comment: It occurs to me to take the formula for the nth Fibonacci number and add $a^n$, run on a computer until I find a counterexample

Comment: For $a=13$ the values $n=42690$ (47555 digits) and $n=45288$ (50449 digits) result in PRP's for all prime bases less than 100. (giving a very high chance of primality).

Comment: The same holds for $a=48$ with $n=55211$ (92824 digits). For $a\in \{ 19,43,51,57 \}$ I have checked all $n < 100\ 000$ without finding a prime.

Comment: The next open cases are $59,61,85,87,93,97,99$. @jorisperrenet You are invited to work on those cases as well. Thanks in advance and also for the computations you already did.

Comment: I searched 59 up to 67k, 61 up to 75k, 85 up to 87k, 87 up to 70k, 93 up to 66k, 97 up to 63k, and 99 up to 58.5k. All searches did not return any PRP's.